# How to compute the implied probability of default from a CDS spread?

Tags: cds, default-probability

I have two tasks:

1. Given country's CDS spread draw implied probability of default.
2. Given probability of default calculate CDS spread.

If possible, refer to any papers.

Comment: Many answers to this old question already, I'll just point out that the conversion to/from roak-neutral (not physical) probability of default and CDS quote also needs the recovery assumption, and that some numbers will change somewhat depending on the recovery assumption.

Answer (score 16):

Risk-neutral default probability implied from CDS is approximately $P=1-e^\frac{-S * t}{1-R}$, where $S$ is the flat CDS spread and $R$ is the recovery rate.

The CDS Spread can be solved using the inverse:

$$S=\ln(1-P) \frac{R-1}{t}$$

- $S$ is the spread expressed in percentage terms (not basis points)
- $t$ are the years to maturity
- $R$ is the recovery rate in percentage terms

Hulls equation is a gross simplification. This equation is not perfect, but is far more accurate and works for all tenor points. It generally works well except when approaching boundary conditions (distressed credits).

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I believe the answer can be further improved for all those being directed here by google after 3 years.

A common way to model the default probability is by the hazard rate. As @Bob correctly mentions, a traditional requirement is for it to satisfy (see [Option Futures and Other Derivatives](https://shamit8.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/options-futures-and-other-derivatives-8th-john.pdf) section 23.4 in which the author discusses also other more exact approximations):
$$\lambda(t)=\frac{S(t)}{1-R}.$$
This is associated with the default probability by (see [Poisson Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process)):
$$P(t,t+h)=\lambda(t)h+o(h)\,,$$
with $P(t,t+h)$ the probability of a default occurring between $t$ and $t+h$. Therefore:
$$P(0,T)=\int_0^T(1-P(0,t))P(t,t+dt)=\int_0^T\lambda(t)(1-P(0,t))dt\,,$$
where the first term of the integral is "default has not occurred so far" and the second is "default occurs on the next time step". This means that $P$ satisfies:
$$\frac{dP(0,t)}{dt}=\lambda(t)(1-P(0,t)).$$
If the CDS is assumed to be constant then $\lambda$ is constant and a solution would be:
$$P(0,t)=1-\exp\left(\frac{-St\,\,\,}{1-R}\right).$$
Equivalently solution for the CDS is:
$$S=\frac{R-1}{t}\log(1-P(0,t)).$$

Comment: Noting that to convert the derivation above to approximation $\lambda(t)=\frac{S(t)}{1-R}$ keep in mind $\exp{(x)}\approx 1+x$ for small $x$.

Comment: Its possible that the P(0,T) inside the integral is instead P(0,t)

Comment: Recovery rate does not make sense for me, the higer the recovery rate the higer the probability of default (I think it should be in the oposite way)

Comment: @david.t_92 If you raise the recovery rate, yet your spread is equal, then that means that you expect the country to default more likely

Comment: Yes, Credit spread = (1 - Recovery Rate) * Default probability, 2 bonds with same credit spread the one with the highest rr have the highest default probability as with this one the probability to recover something if default is higher

Thanks a lot @DiegoFMedina

Comment: Thanks for giving its mathematical derivation (integrating a Poisson process function).

Answer (score 9):

The chapter in [Hull](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133456315) on Credit Risk gives the same formula as emcor as a first approximation with a justification:

> Consider first an approximate calculation. Suppose that a bond yields 200 basis points more than a similar risk-free bond and that the expected recovery rate in the event of a default is 40%. The holder of a corporate bond must be expecting to lose 200 basis points (or 2% per year) from defaults. Given the recovery rate of 40%, this leads to an estimate of the probability of a default per year conditional on no earlier default of $0.02/(1-04)$, or 3.33%. In general $$ \bar{\lambda} = \frac{s}{1-R}$$
>   where $\bar{\lambda}$ is the average default intensity (hazard rate) per year, $s$ is the spread of the corporate bond yield over the risk-free rate, and $R$ is the expected recovery rate.

This formula can easily be rewritten as 
$$s = \bar{\lambda} (1 -R)$$ 
as pointed out by @emcor.

User @lakesh pointed in a deleted question to [a blog by Donald van Deventer](http://www.kamakuraco.com/Blog/tabid/231/EntryId/700/Credit-Spreads-and-Default-Probabilities-A-Simple-Model-Validation-Example.aspx) that analyses this formula and he rejects it.

Both Hull and van Deventer remark that this formula is an imperfect approximation. It makes sense but there are some caveats and a number of improvements can be made and Hull gives one you can readily do yourself. What is best probably depends on the goal of the study.

Comment: I came across your answer after remembering this equation but wanting to think it through a bit more. I understand th broad intuition, but when I start to vary `R` I start to have some questions. Why is it that as R->0 (which should imply more risk?) does lambda become lower. If I assume 0 recovery, i have 100% loss at default. As R->1 lambda->large. Is this not unintuitive? I may be bungling something obvious.

Comment: @jasonm Better for visibility and our formatto have this as a separate question (maybe referencing this).

Answer (score 5):

From this [research](http://www.dbresearch.com/PROD/DBR_INTERNET_EN-PROD/PROD0000000000183612.pdf) from Deutsche Bank, :
$$p_{def}=\frac{CDS_{spread}}{1-Rec}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow CDS_{spread}=p_{def}(1-Rec)$$
where $Rec$ is the recovery rate in case of default.

Comment: I just wanted to add that emcor's answer is almost correct but not quite. What he wrote as $p_{def}$ is not actually the probability of default, but rather the probability per unit time, or the "default intensity", i.e. if the probability of defaulting by time t is Q(0,T), then we have the diff eq $dQ(0,T) = p_{def}Q(0,T)dt$ with $Q(0,0)=0$ so that $Q(0,T) = exp(-p_{def}T)$

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to Quant.SE! I converted your answer to a comment for you. When you gather some reputation you will be able to does this yourself.